# symfony cache dir /dev/shm in production?

Tags: symfony, caching, shared-memory

You can define a custom cache dir in `Kernel.php` and use the shared memory via `/dev/shm`

```php
public function getCacheDir(): string
{
  return '/dev/shm/sf-cache/'.$this->environment;
}
```

*This is somewhat recommended for developing on virtual machines on non-linux systems like vagrant / docker, as it significantly speeds up things there.*

Could you also use that in production as a faster filesystem alternative?
If not, why? What are potential downsides?

Comment: Yes, you can use it production, I have used it where the project files are on a shared networked drive which is a slow cache, so set the cache directory to a the nodes tmp directory to speed up cache access. Not sure if there are any ups or downsides as this depends on your use case and deployment infastructure.